# jQuery select dropdown and selectedq

Tags: jquery

```
   var colorID = 3;
   $('#color').each(function(){
   if($('#color').val() == colorID )
      $('#color').attr('selected');
   });
```

Why doesn't this work?

My html

```
<select id="color"><option value="">Select Color</option>
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Black</option>
<option value="4">Purple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get/set the value of any input style element, including a `<select>`:

```
$('#color').val(3);
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/R57Ud/). For illustration here's a working long-hand version of what you were attempting:

```
var colorID = 3;
$('#color option').each(function(){
if ($(this).val() == colorID)
  $(this).attr('selected', true);
});
```

You were looping through but then checking the `<select>`, not the `<option>` elements, which doesn't have those properties.

Comment: Wasn't it `selected="selected"` instead of true? true works in upto 2 browsers as far as I remember.

Comment: @naugtur - DOM != markup, it's a boolean property :) The reason `"selected"` works is that any non-empty string is "true" as well.  Also in markup it's *supposed* to be just `selected`, no equals or value :)  The above will work for all browsers :)

Comment: I can't remember, but I had some problems with that once. In an old browser.

Comment: @naugtur - do remember that jQuery normalizes some things under the hood as well.  When you *get* this attribute, for example: `.attr("selected")` you'll get a boolean `true`/`false` coming out as well :)

Comment: that's right. That memory of mine was from 3 years before. Sorry for making a fuss ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var colorID = '3';
   $('#color option').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == colorID)
        {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
   });
```

Comment: Cool, but  `$(this).attr('selected');` is a getter, and that's the problem.